# Random number generation between two integers using arc4random()

Tags: ios, objective-c, math, random

I have an NSArray whose `.count` I store into an integer named `arrayCount`

I need to generate a random number from 0 to `arrayCount` but when I used arc4random() it generates a really large integer.

I've been doing this : `int randomInt = arc4random()*arrayCount;`

Which has been giving me random numbers like 12309120 and such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `arc4random_uniform` instead, which is specifically designed to generate numbers in the range [0,n) (like array indices). It is better than simple `arc4random() % n` because it avoids the bias introduced by the modulo operator.

You'd use it as `arc4random_uniform(arrayCount)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
int randomInt = arc4random() % arrayCount;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do the modulus instead

```
int randomInt = arc4random() % arrayCount;
```

This will give you values between (inclusive) `0` and `arrayCount-1` or `[0, arrayCount)` if you prefer